# Reverse Transformer For Smooth High Voltage

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, transformer, high-voltage, vacuum-tube

So I want to make a valve audio preamp, but need a way to generate clean high voltage DC for the plates of my tubes. I started with rolling my own boost converter which worked well, but was unable to reach my desired voltage (about 200 V) as it was to much to ask from a single stage starting voltage of 12 V.

After some searching I came across this circuit which uses a step down transformer in reverse:
[image: 4S Tube Power Supply]

This looked nice and simple and began working on my schematic:
[image: My circuit1]

I added a MOSFET 'capacitance multiplier' as I want my supply to be as ripple free as possible, as well as the voltage climbing slowly will help in the following sections. C2 and C3 are probably over-kill but I have them in stock so may-swell.

The regulator is to power the filaments of two tubes and is tested and works great. My tubes only allow a 6.3 V connection.

So my first step down transformer is an enclosed 240 Vac primary, 12 Vac secondary, 36 VA. Picture here:

[image: transformer1]

And my second 'step up' (backwards) transformer:

[image: transformer2]

I have tested the low voltage side and regulator circuit, which seems to work perfectly.

I need about 220 V that supports a current draw of 20-30 mA.

My first question is are these transformers ideal for the application? giving that Transformer 1 gives about 13.5 Vac loaded with 1amp. how much can I expect on the high voltage side?

I plan to use large 470 uF 450 V capacitors (C2, C3) overkill I know. Is inrush current a concern on the coils?

I'm guessing the 0.01uf capacitors in parallel with the bridge rectifier diodes are to suppress EMF and high frequencies. Are these worth including?

For grounding, I plan to connect the grounds of the high voltage and low voltage side together and connect to the chassis that prevents the chassis becoming live. Is this the right approach?

I know this is a few questions rolled into one, but as my first high voltage project I want to make sure I get everything right.
Thank you!

Comment: It strikes me that your boost converter not reaching 200 volts was a limitation in how you designed it. I see no great reason why a 12 volt to 200 volt boost circuit would not work really well. It's all about component selection. A flyback design would also really suit this type of output voltage and power.

Comment: It seems to be a known limitation with simple (single inductor) boost converters. I have looked into using a flyback switching transformer which would seem to be best, however, finding a suitable transformer was an issue. this along with added complexity and large amount of switching noise made me look into this approach instead.

Comment: I've made boost converters that produced 900 volts from 12 volts.

Comment: Single inductor? at what wattage?

Comment: It was part of a Cuk converter that could produce over 1 kW. In the initial design stages I tested it at much lower power from a lab/bench supply on 12 volts. The front inductor of a Cuk converter is just an inverting boost design hence, although the Cuk converter requires 2 inductors to operate as we wanted, the principle of generating 900 volts from the boost inductor stage of a Cuk converter was proven satisfactorily to me.

Comment: hmm it looks like a promising and interesting approach. having capacitor coupling between to inductors? but would be a lot harder to engineer as my first high voltage project. but I'm gonna do some simulations anyway, thank you.

Comment: You might be missing my point. My point is that although a Cuk converter produces a negative output from a positive input (not what you want or need), the first inductor stage behaves exactly like a regular boost converter (but inverted) hence, a regular boost converter can produce high voltages.

Comment: Why use a double transformer arrangement when a transformer suitable for a vacuum tube B+ supply is not hard to obtain? Why be so fussy about the exact voltage?

Comment: I'm not so fussy about the voltage, between 200 V and 300 V will be fine, I could always tweak that with the voltage divider R2/R3 anyway (heat dissipation permitting). I've not found a single suitable transformer that isn't much more expensive than a double transformer approach.

Comment: Congratulations on not only isolating yourself from the mains, but doing it with a CE marked wall-wart.